# Finding out what browser is still open

Tags: windows, process, browser

I keep getting a "you have a browser open" dialog on my Windows system.

I can't seen to find the one that is open.

How do I find this out?

Comment: Start by telling us which operating system you're using.

Answer (score 5):

press ctrl+alt+delete and click the process tab, find there the name of your browser, example firefox, usually you will see there a visible process named firefox.exe, so if your browser is firefox and you want to close it, just click it and select end process at the lower part of the task manager window.